# Calculation of two double fields different between Access and C#

Tags: c#

So I'm in the process of converting an application that has been running in Access for years and now going to C#/web application.  It deals with some pretty exact math and I've run into a problem with calculation of two double values.

So in Access I have the following code:

```
If Abs(varPartDataLocal(i, 0) - dblX_Star) < dblTemp Then
```

Where varPartDataLocal(i, 0) = 1.00000232 (stored as string in a database) and dblX_Star = 1.00000226 (calculated by two string values that are converted to double and divided by 2) and when I get the Abs of those two values in Access I get:

> 5.999999986E-08

whereas when I do the same code in C#:

```
if (Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(varPartDataLocal[i, 0]) - dblX_Star) < dblTemp)
```

I end us with:

> 6.0000000079441E-08

However, if I do this in C# (basically the same as above I'm just not converting it from string to double):

```
Math.Abs(1.00000232d - 1.00000226d)
```

then I get

> 5.99999998573963E-08 (which is the same as when I do this in Access)

So the question is why the difference?

Comment: The Math can't be that exact when it's performed using doubles.

Comment: `which is the same as above`, same as which?

Comment: Sorry, I was saying that 5.99999998573963E-08 (in my last formula where I just use the numbers as double) is the same as 5.999999986E-08 when I use Access.  In C# I'm converting the variable varPartDataLocal from string (as that is what it's stored in the database) to Double.  Maybe that is my problem.

Comment: I cleared up the question to try to be more precise in what I was asking and what I've done.  I tried taking out my conversion and doing that in it's own variable and multiple it by 100 and divide by 100 to make sure that wasn't the issue.  So I did this:

double dbVar = (Convert.ToDouble(varPartDataLocal[I,0]);
dbVar = dbVar * 100 / 100;
if (Math.Abs(dbVar - dblX_Star) < dblTemp)

But I still end up with the 6.0000000079441E-08 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the code below gives the same answer regardless of how I obtain the values, I'd suggest that your problem lies in the calculation of `dblX_Star`, which is not shown in your question.

```
const double dbl1 = 1.00000232d;
const double dbl2 = 1.00000226d;
double rslt1 = dbl1 - dbl2;

const string str1 = "1.00000232";
const string str2 = "1.00000226";

double d1 = double.Parse(str1);
double d2 = double.Parse(str2);

double rslt2 = d1 - d2;

double dd1 = Convert.ToDouble(str1);
double dd2 = Convert.ToDouble(str2);
double rslt3 = dd1 - dd2;

Console.WriteLine("rslt1 = {0}", rslt1);
Console.WriteLine("rslt2 = {0}", rslt2);
Console.WriteLine("rslt3 = {0}", rslt3);
```

The output from that is:

```
rslt1 = 5.99999998573963E-08
rslt2 = 5.99999998573963E-08
rslt3 = 5.99999998573963E-08
```

Comment: Jim - what I don't understand is why does it equal 5.99999998573963E-08 in the first place?  Should it not be .00000006?  I found that if I do the same math in Excel I get .0000006 but if I continue to add more and more decimal points then suddenly I get this strange additional numbers.  I'm going to throw the above into my web page and see if the results are the same.  I was getting different results when doing the string conversion vs the setting it directly.  The value of dblX_Star is a string set to the value and converted to double above.  Thanks, Richard